# Will the Redis Store 5MB limit work for session support in Express?

Tags: redis, session-cookies, express

How much data do sessions take in general. If I'm expecting traffic around a 1000 hits a day, will the 5MB limit of the free plan of Redis hosts work for me?

Comment: To save space minimise the lifetime of the sessions, so that you don't have old session data hanging around. But why not just host redis yourself?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type of data structure is used to store individual sessions. Take a look at [this article](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1010844204/redis-memory-usage) which summarize memory usage of data structures provided by redis. It might be a little bit outdated in terms of [memory optimisation](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization) but it's still a good resource to get a rough estimate.